# Cannot read property '######' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I have a two JSON arrays, `$scope.pl`  and `$scope.activepage`, which contain values,

```
 $scope.pl = [{
   pageid: 1,
   page: "regions",
   menudId: 2
  },
  {
   pageid: 2,
   page: "countries",
   menudId: 2
  },
  {
   pageid: 3,
   page: "location",
   menudId: 2
  },
  {
   pageid: 4,
   page: "street",
   menudId: 2
  },
  {
   pageid: 5,
   page: "door",
   menudId: 2
  }
 ]
 $scope.removepl = [{
   pageid: 1,
   page: "regions",
   menuId: 2
  },
  {
   pageid: 1,
   page: "countries",
   menuId: 2
  }
 ]
```

Now I have to remove the values of `$scope.removepl`
which is inisde the `$scope.pl`

```
 for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.removepl.length; i++) {
  $scope.pagelists = _.filter($scope.pl, function(res) {
   return res.pageid !== $scope.removepl[i].pageid;
  });
  $scope.pl = $scope.pagelists;
 }
```

Now its working properly, but I get an error in the console like

> cannot read property "pageid" of undefined

could this be caused by `$scope.removepl[i].pageid` I'm using in for loop for iteration?

Does anybody have solution for that?

Comment: There is no pageid , it is id instead

Comment: As @HarmandeepSinghKalsi has said you need to change .pageid for .id. Also you need to change the `for` comparison for `i < $scope.removepl.length` as with your code it will access to a memory position that doesn't exist

Comment: @Jon do you have any solution for that,can you pls once again check my question i made the changes now properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can do something like this. I have tried with `arr1` and `arr2` make changes accordingly.

Duplicate from `arr2` will get removed from `arr1` and will be stored in `result` variable

```js
const arr1 = [{
   id: 1,
   page: "regions",
   menudId: 2
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   page: "countries",
   menudId: 2
  },
  {
   id: 3,
   page: "location",
   menudId: 2
  },
  {
   id: 4,
   page: "street",
   menudId: 2
  },
  {
   id: 5,
   page: "door",
   menudId: 2
  }
 ]
 const arr2 = [{
   id: 1,
   page: "regions",
   menuId: 2
  },
  {
   id: 1,
   page: "countries",
   menuId: 2
  }
 ]

var result = arr1.reduce(function (prev, value) {

    var isDuplicate = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        if (value.id == arr2[i].id) {
            isDuplicate = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (!isDuplicate) {
        prev.push(value);
    }
    
    return prev;
    
}, []);


console.log(result);
```